# Understanding Recompose and migrate to React hooks

Tags: reactjs, recompose

Suddenly I get an npm error in the pipeline that my [recompose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recompose) package is not compatible with React version 17.

So I have to remove the recompose package. I try to understand why/how it's used in our codebase and what adjustments I have to make to get everything working.

For example I have a file `App.tsx` and `App.container.ts`.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { compose } from 'recompose';

import App from './App';
import { InnerProps, OuterProps } from './App.types';
import withAppCookie from './with-app-cookie';

export default compose<InnerProps, OuterProps>(withRouter, withAppCookie)(App);
```

We are using only the [compose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose) utility from the Recompose package.

In above case why is `compose` utility used and what adjustments do I have to make to get it working without this package?